# Updates in a Postgres Timescale DB

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a Postgres Timescale database with a table that contains about 2.5 million records.

The Primary Key is on two columns, device and time, there is a subsequent index on these columns also, and another on the time column only.

The problems I'm experiencing are:

1. I need to do a one off update of a new column to populate it via a
   calculation from existing columns, but tests so far indicate this
   will be a very slow process.
2. Performing an update on a single record identified by the device and
   time columns can be instant, or very slow, even if the record is
   only an hour or so old.

Tom

Comment: I see no SQL and no `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output in your question.

Comment: Also, if you have an index on columns (X,Y), there is no need for a second index on just X.

Comment: Can you also show the schema and the index definitions by calling `\d table_name`?